# How to display a .java file in a textview?

Tags: java, android, formatting, textview

Apps like AIME and "Java Programs" display java code with proper formatting, indentation, and coloring so the user can see actual java code in the app. How is this done?

Comment: I knew this answer was out there and that I just needed the right search query. Thanks for pointing me to it! Put it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Actually, the correct process for duplicates is to mark them as duplicates, as I just did here, rather than have duplicate answers floating about.

Comment: thanks...I will certainly mimick in the future

Answer (score 0):

Well you a proper Code Text Editor if you are Dos Programmer I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org)  and you can use it to format your Java Code :) Otherwise you can use an IDE Like Netbeans

Comment: While I agree that Notepad++ is a great app for displaying .java files, I want to display them in an app rather than on my computer.

Comment: Then you can use Formatting depends on Language if You are using HTML then you could use CPPBrush I'd Share the Code if u like ... and for Java I just googled it for you [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21484/colorviewer-mini-app-for-viewing-colors-in-different-formats)